# Need help making my code shorter!! (Noob here)

Tags: java, android, for-loop

My code works, I just need help making it shorter and more efficient. I think a for-loop should work, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    double loanAmount = Integer.parseInt(mLoanAmount.getText().toString());
    double interestRate = Double.parseDouble(mInterestRate.getText().toString());
    double rate = ((interestRate/100)/12);
    double rate5 = Math.pow((1 + rate) , (-12*5));
    double rate10 = Math.pow((1 + rate) , (-12*10));
    double rate15 = Math.pow((1 + rate) , (-12*15));
    double rate20 = Math.pow((1 + rate) , (-12*20));
    double rate25 = Math.pow((1 + rate) , (-12*25));
    double monthlyPayment5 = ((loanAmount * rate)/(1 - rate5));
    double monthlyPayment10 = ((loanAmount * rate)/(1 - rate10));
    double monthlyPayment15 = ((loanAmount * rate)/(1 - rate15));
    double monthlyPayment20 = ((loanAmount * rate)/(1 - rate20));
    double monthlyPayment25 = ((loanAmount * rate)/(1 - rate25));

    mMonthly5.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment5));
    mMonthly10.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment10));
    mMonthly15.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment15));
    mMonthly20.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment20));
    mMonthly25.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment25));
}
```

if you notice my code is very repetitive, the only thing that changes is a number in the variable name.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code instead of a image. use methods, and pass in what you need to get what you want.

Comment: Hi Raulyn, often you can actually ask your ide to do this for you. Intellij is very good at reformating and optimizing things. So I'd suggest you google whatever ide you are using + "how to reformat / optimize" + name of ide. But if you really want direct feedback on how to shorten / improve your code I'd recommend pasting the actual code. Although remember that people on stackoverflow can be very harsh. (See above comment)

Comment: I'm new to Stackoverflow. I tried showing the code but it keeps saying something like not properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be rewritten to

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    double loanAmount = Integer.parseInt(mLoanAmount.getText().toString());
    double interestRate = Double.parseDouble(mInterestRate.getText().toString());

    double baseRate = ((interestRate/100)/12);

    double rates[] = {-12*5, -12*10, -12*15, -12*20, -12*25};
    TextView views = {mMonthly5, mMonthly10, mMonthly15, mMonthly20, mMonthly25};

    for(int i=0; i<rates.length; i++) {
        double actualRate = Math.pow((1 + baseRate) , rates[i]);
        double monthlyPayment = ((loanAmount * baseRate)/(1 - actualRate));
        views[i].setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(monthlyPayment));
    }
}
```

I hope this example will be helpful for you in the future.

Comment: you nailed it. `mMonthly5` was a TextView type. The only other thing I had to fix was `monthlyPayntent5`,  it had to be just `monthlyPayntent` (on the last line). Thank you. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Oops, sorry :) Code fixed